# Taking the inverse of a one-to-one polynomial

Tags: graphing-functions, inverse-function, transcendental-functions

I'm trying to take the inverse of:

$$f(x)=\frac{4x^3}{x^2+1}$$

When looking at the graph, it seems to be fully inversible (it is one-to-one), so I should be able to end up with another equation that is mirrored in the $x=y$ axis. However, I cannot get the formula in its nicest form, a form where the $y$ term is only on the left.

My process: exchange x and y, and try to solve for y:

$$x=\frac{4y^3}{y^2+1}$$
$$x(y^2+1)=4y^3$$
$$xy^2+x=4y^3$$
$$4y^3-xy^2=x$$
$$y^2(4y-x)=x$$
$$y^2=\frac{x}{4y-x}$$
$$f^-1(x)=y=\sqrt{\frac{x}{4y-x}}$$

This does seem to be correct, but the equation has a stray $y$ on the right side which I cant get rid of. Also, the inverse function has lost half of its graph because of the root.

So is $f(x)$ fully inversible, and if so how do I achieve this form?

Comment: A rather ugly solution is to write $4y^3 -xy^2 -x=0$ and use a general formula for the cubic (like [these classics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula). I'm not sure a "nice" formula exists.

Comment: It's not always the case that a "nice" inverse formula will exist, just as @HennoBrandsma has pointed out. However, one will exist, as you have pointed out

Comment: Thanks, it amazes me how $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $f(x)=x^3$ are perfect brothers, but something cannot be achieved nicely for the equation above. Is it possible that it still exists although in a short form we cant (yet) derive?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. Is my solution so ugly ?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose; Is my solution so ugly ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's OK. But probably not what the OP expected (namely a polynomial of sorts with roots).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici not at all! I think this is a nice solution. But it's still incredibly complicated when compared with the original function, which is what I was trying to refer to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real solution of the [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) $4 x^3 = (x^2 + 1) y$  (for $y \ne 0$) is

$$ x = \frac{1}{12} \left(\sqrt [3]{216\,y+{y}^{3}+12\,\sqrt {3\,{y}^{4}+324\,{y}^{2}}}+
{\frac {{y}^{2}}{\sqrt [3]{216\,y+{y}^{3}+12\,\sqrt {3\,{y}^{4}+
324\,{y}^{2}}}}}+y\right)
$$

Comment: wow, I would have never expected this equation to be that long. Indeed it checks out exactly. Upon further inspection of the question I was trying to solve, it appears that I had to use some properties of inverse function derivatives to calculate just $(f^{-1})^`(2)$. But nevertheless it answered my question :)

Answer (score 4):

The cubic equation being
$$4x^3-y x^2-y=0$$ we have $$\Delta=-4 y^2 \left(y^2+108\right) \quad < 0 \quad \forall y$$ So, only one real root. Using the hyperbolic method, we then have

$$x=\frac{1}{12} y \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(1+\frac{216}{y^2}\right)\right)\right)$$